# How to filter results in jQuery with multiple selects, including a date range?

Tags: jquery, filter, date-range

I'm trying to filter results based on data attributes. For the most part I think I'm there (it works on the first 3 selectors), but I get into trouble trying to take the date selector into the equation.
At this point I question of my approach is correct altogether - I can change HTML if required - so feel free to provide a better solution.

For the convenience of anyone willing to help here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rnbx0c3j/

THANK YOU

Selectors:

```
<div id="stats_filter">
    <div id="stats_filter_wrapper" class="grids">
        <div class="grid-3 select-wrapper server first">
            <label class="server">Server</label>
            <select id="select-server">
                <option value="all">All</option>
                <option value="NicNicFunGame">NicNicFunGame</option>
                <option value="GT3_races">GT3_races</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-3 select-wrapper track">
            <label class="track">Track</label>
            <select id="select-track">
                <option value="all">All</option>
                <option value="ks_brands_hatch">ks_brands_hatch</option>
                <option value="Imola">Imola</option>
                <option value="Spa">Spa</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-3 select-wrapper car">
            <label class="car">Car</label>
            <select id="select-car">
                <option value="all">All</option>
                <option value="ariel_atom_v8">ariel_atom_v8</option>
                <option value="rr_caterham_academy_620r">rr_caterham_academy_620r</option>
                <option value="ks_porsche_911_gt1">ks_porsche_911_gt1</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-3 select-wrapper date">
            <label class="date">Date</label>
            <select id="select-date">
                <option value="all">All</option>
                <option value="7">Last 7 days</option>
                <option value="30">Last 30 days</option>
                <option value="182">Last 6 months</option>
                <option value="365">Last 12 months</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

HTML to be filtered

```
<div class="stats-section" id="sectionID_1" data-server="NicNicFunGame" data-track="ks_brands_hatch" data-date="27/09/2019" data-car="ariel_atom_v8">sectionID_1</div>
<div class="stats-section" id="sectionID_2" data-server="NicNicFunGame" data-track="Imola" data-date="03/07/2019" data-car="rr_caterham_academy_620r">sectionID_2</div>
<div class="stats-section" id="sectionID_3" data-server="GT3_races" data-track="Spa" data-date="14/01/2019" data-car="ariel_atom_v8, ks_porsche_911_gt1">sectionID_3</div>
```

JS

```
var $select = $('#stats_filter select');
var $statsSection = $('.stats-section');

$select.change(function () {
    var include = '';
    var exclude = [];
    var showAll = true;
    var filterDate = false;

    $select.each(function () {
        var val = $(this).children(':selected').val();

        if (val !== 'all') {

            switch ($(this).prop('id')) {
                case 'select-server':
                    include += "[data-server='" + val + "']";
                    break;
                case 'select-track':
                    include += "[data-track='" + val + "']";
                    break;
                case 'select-car':
                    include += "[data-car*='" + val + "']";
                    break;
                case 'select-date':
                    var selectedDate = new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() - val));
                    var dd = selectedDate.getDate();
                    var mm = selectedDate.getMonth() + 1;
                    var yyyy = selectedDate.getFullYear();
                    if (dd < 10) {
                        dd = '0' + dd;
                    }
                    if (mm < 10) {
                        mm = '0' + mm;
                    }
                    selectedDate = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + yyyy;

                    //exclude when date is out of range
                    $statsSection.each(function () {
                        var sectionDate = $(this).data('date');

                        if (process(sectionDate) < process(selectedDate)) {
                            exclude.push("[data-date='" + sectionDate + "']");
                        }
                        exclude.join(',');

                    });

                    function process(date) {
                        var parts = date.split("/");
                        return new Date(parts[2], parts[1] - 1, parts[0]);
                    }

                    filterDate = true;
                    break;
            }
            showAll = false;
        }

    });

    if (showAll) {
        $statsSection.show();
    } else {


        //HOW TO DEAL WITH THE DATES??
                if (filterDate == true) {
            alert('the following dates should be excluded from the results: ' + exclude);
        }

        //this works for the non-date selectors
        $statsSection.not($(include)).hide();
        $statsSection.filter($(include)).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Why don't you use something like [alasql](https://github.com/agershun/alasql)

Comment: I see the data includes a date parameter. Why not compare the date.UTC() of the computed filter date to the date.UTC() value of the data points? The UTC function gives a pure number of milliseconds since 1970 so your data range will work fine with it. If you have a large data set to filter you can make a data-utc parameter for each data node as a loading process so as to avoid recomputing later.

Comment: @Vanquished Wombat Thx for the UTC tip, I surely look into it.
However my main problem is not the dates themselves (probably my question was not clear enough).
The main problem: I already have an array [exclude] with the correct data attributes to exclude (or include) from the results, but I fail to understand how to make it work from here and filter the correct results based on the date selector (see the fiddle above >> select date). Thx!

Comment: @angel.bonev I prefer not to include yet another library for something that can be done in plain JS / jQuery (unless there's a very good reason for it)

Comment: @NicoF i see, but searching with selectors is not very fast, managing it will be hard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, for the non-date items your technique is to compute the jquery selector for elements that should be included, then apply that to the data divs.

Quite a nice approach in that you are constructing multiple jquery filters as you build up the 'include' variable.

The difficulty in applying the same technique for the dates is that this produces a range test which is hard to put into a jquery selector. My solution is to construct an array of qualifying data-date values and carry out a second filter in the final step.

The changes are:

Step 1. Define a new variable:

```
var dateInclude = [];
```

Step 2. In the section where you determine if the date is valid push the valid values into the dataInclude filters array

```
//exclude when date is out of range
$statsSection.each(function () {
    var sectionDate = $(this).data('date');

    if (process(sectionDate) > process(selectedDate)) {
        dateInclude.push("[data-date='" + sectionDate + "']");
    }

});
```

Step 3: In the output section we now combine the dateInclude as a second filter. Note that your initial filters operate as boolean AND, but the date filters have to operate as boolean OR's. Therefore the dateInclude filter is applied in the show() operation as a second step.

```
$statsSection.hide();
include = (dateInclude.length > 0 && include === '' ? '*' : include);
dateInclude = (dateInclude.length === 0 ? ['*'] : dateInclude );
$('#info').html(include + ' :: ' + dateInclude.join());
$statsSection.filter(include).filter(dateInclude.join()).show();
```

The first line (below) hides all the data divs pre-emptively.

```
$statsSection.hide();
```

The next lines (below) operate on the filters to ensure that they both have a value. If no date filters are present we inject a match-all, and same for the 'include' filters for the other select boxes.

```
include = (dateInclude.length > 0 && include === '' ? '*' : include);
dateInclude = (dateInclude.length === 0 ? ['*'] : dateInclude );
```

Finally we bring this together as below.

```
$statsSection.filter(include).filter(dateInclude.join()).show();
```

To help visualise it I added some output to the fiddle

For example, selecting server=NicNicFunGame and date=last six months produces filters:

```
$statsSection.filter("[data-server='NicNicFunGame']").filter("[data-date='27/09/2019'],[data-date='03/07/2019']").show();
```

See my working fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/JamesE442/qktfbp15/38/

Comment: Hi this is awesome, thank you so much. As you can read in my comment to angel.bonev, it's very fast too! Thanks again mate

Answer (score 1):

You can store all of your `stats-section` into array of objects and search  with [array filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
var t0 = performance.now(); 
var initialized = false;
var $select = $('#stats_filter select'); 
function initialize() {
  mySelectors = [];
  $statsSection = $('.stats-section');
    console.log("First search will be costly");
    $($statsSection).each(function (i, e) {
        let temp = $(e).data();
        temp.element = $(e);
        let myDate = temp.date.split("/");
        temp.date = new Date(myDate[1] + "/" + myDate[0] + "/" + myDate[2]).getTime();//fix date format and convert to timestamp
        mySelectors.push(temp);
    });
    initialized = true;
}



$select.change(function () {
    var t0 = performance.now();
    if (!initialized)
        initialize();
    var result = mySelectors;
    $select.each(function () {
        var val = $(this).val(); //you don't need to search the selected child
        if (val !== 'all') {
            switch ($(this).prop('id')) {
                case 'select-server':
                    result = result.filter(obj => {
                        return obj.server === val;
                    });
                    break;
                case 'select-track':
                    result = result.filter(obj => {
                        return obj.track === val;
                    });
                    break;
                case 'select-car':
                    result = result.filter(obj => {
                        return obj.car === val;
                    });
                    break;
                case 'select-date':
                    var selectedDate = new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() - val)).getTime(); // timestamp
                    result = result.filter(obj => {
                        return obj.date > selectedDate;
                    });
            }
        }

    });
    $($statsSection).hide();
    $.each(result, function (i, e) {
        $(e.element).show();
    });
    var t1 = performance.now();
    console.log("Search performance " + (t1 - t0) + " milliseconds.");
});
var t1 = performance.now();
console.log("Initialize performance " + (t1 - t0) + " milliseconds.");
```

```css
.grids { clear: both;max-width: 1920px;margin: 0;}
#stats_filter_wrapper .select-wrapper { width: 25%; float:left; }
#stats_filter_wrapper .select-wrapper label { overflow: hidden; font-weight: 700; }
#stats_filter_wrapper .select-wrapper select { display: block; font-size: 16px; color: #6a6d73; line-height: 1.3; padding: 8px 25px 5px 8px; width: 100%; max-width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0; }
.stats-section{padding:20px 0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="stats_filter">
    <div id="stats_filter_wrapper" class="grids">
        <div class="grid-3 select-wrapper server first">
            <label class="server">Server</label>
            <select id="select-server">
                <option value="all">All</option>
                <option value="NicNicFunGame">NicNicFunGame</option>
                <option value="GT3_races">GT3_races</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-3 select-wrapper track">
            <label class="track">Track</label>
            <select id="select-track">
                <option value="all">All</option>
                <option value="ks_brands_hatch">ks_brands_hatch</option>
                <option value="Imola">Imola</option>
                <option value="Spa">Spa</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-3 select-wrapper car">
            <label class="car">Car</label>
            <select id="select-car">
                <option value="all">All</option>
                <option value="ariel_atom_v8">ariel_atom_v8</option>
                <option value="rr_caterham_academy_620r">rr_caterham_academy_620r</option>
                <option value="ks_porsche_911_gt1">ks_porsche_911_gt1</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-3 select-wrapper date">
            <label class="date">Date</label>
            <select id="select-date">
                <option value="all">All</option>
                <option value="7">Last 7 days</option>
                <option value="30">Last 30 days</option>
                <option value="182">Last 6 months</option>
                <option value="365">Last 12 months</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="stats-section" id="sectionID_1" data-server="NicNicFunGame" data-track="ks_brands_hatch" data-date="27/09/2019" data-car="ariel_atom_v8">sectionID_1</div>
<div class="stats-section" id="sectionID_2" data-server="NicNicFunGame" data-track="Imola" data-date="03/07/2019" data-car="rr_caterham_academy_620r">sectionID_2</div>
<div class="stats-section" id="sectionID_3" data-server="GT3_races" data-track="Spa" data-date="14/01/2019" data-car="ariel_atom_v8, ks_porsche_911_gt1">sectionID_3</div>
```

Comment: hi man, thx a lot. I love how clean this approach is (and I'm banging my head on the wall why I didn't see this)! However FYI, I tested your code against the one of Vanquished Wombat here below, and I see a significant difference in performance even on only 3 results (0.344970703125ms versus 0.864990234375ms for your code). In reality I could get up to 50 results so that's a huge factor here.
I suppose I have to go for his version but many thanks for teaching me something

Comment: what are you benchmarking ? the search or the inizialization?

Comment: As you can see I'm converting you date format to timestamp on inizialization on his code it's done in the search part. You can get both you can initialize after the first change

Comment: ok, cool. FYI the timestamps are on initialisation with 3 sections on the page (each sections contain a bunch of tables/data). Not entirely sure why there is a big difference between the 2 approaches

Comment: I have updated the snippet please check it now and benchmark it and I will explained in that time, but benchmark and the search like me. You have my upvote because you are the first person that cares about performance. It's always faster to compare intigers if you use selectors you'are using some kind ot regex or something

Comment: I'll run some test later on and update.
In regards to performance, I always aim to load a FULL page in 1 sec, and won't publish anything above 2 sec (!). Web page performance is hugely important as I wrote here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B54rxdQiCbiZaUpvZTM0U3Y5SUU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200339/discussion-between-angel-bonev-and-nicof).